# How to make my C# DLL a self registering dll

Tags: c#, com, registry, registration, installshield

I've created a COM object in C# that later get's used by a VBScript. In order for the VBScript to be able to instantiate the object it must be registered. Previously I was registering the object manually using RegAsm tool supplied with any .NET Framework.

However, I am now creating an installer so I can install this object on different machines and when I am using InstallShield 2012 Spring Express it is warning me that the dll is not self registering.

How can I make my DLL self register? I've found guides and examples of folks using the Process object in C# to call RegAsm, but my object is not an executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom actions and Self Registration is *NOT* a best practice.

If your version of InstallShield doesn't support COM Interop, run the command:

regasm foo.dll /regfile:foo.reg

Now import that reg file into InstallShield and tweak things file  foo.dll to [INSTALLDIR]foo.dll.

If your version of InstallShield doesn't support importing reg files,  edit in notepad and enter the values into InstallShield by hand.

This is the cleanest approach as you won't have any custom actions to fail and since MSI is handling the registration it knows how to uninstall and rollback the data.

Comment: When you need generate reg file for ```/codebase```, you can run command like this:
```RegAsm.exe yourpath.dll" /codebase /regfile```
the reg file will be created in your.dll folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InstallShield, you can ask InstallShield to register your typelibs. In **Components** -> YOUR DLL -> **.NET Settings** -> Set **.NET COM Interop** to Yes.

[image: InstallShield setting screenshot]

In case you are using a version of InstallShield that does not support this, write a custom action which calls RegAsm.exe to register your dll.

Comment: My version of InstallShield does not support what you have above. What would the custom action look like? I've got my dll to install in a static location and the user can't change it, which means all I need is to know how to call regasm in the custom action. How do I find regasm's path etc?

Comment: @Tada See if this post helps. http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/primer-on-creating-installscript-custom-actions/ Creating custom action needs some knowledge of InstallShield.

Comment: @Tada As per this article, http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/isxhelp12/IDlgFilePropertiesComNetSettings.htm .NET registration is supported in InstallShield Express too. So there is no reason why your version will not support it.

Comment: This is my point, I've followed that article exactly and I get the error:-4354: The build was unable to extract COM information from the file x in component x.Primary_output. Please ensure that the file is self-registering and verify that the self-registration process does not fail.

Comment: I'll try that first thing tomorrow morning. I know for sure that regasm DLL_NAME /codebase works (i haven't tried with the tlb switch)